# Reseting Index in dataframe on Axis 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, backend

So I am trying to transpose a data that is coming from excel. Once I transpose it the Index numbers are located above the columns..so when I try to reset the index I get something like this:

[image]

The problem is I need column names which I will use later in my project and then I need the data which will match those column names. But it doesnt work since the columns are now indexed numbers.

And what I want is this:

[image]

I tried everything but nothing seems to work, I tried resetting the index at level 0, setting the new index but it always gets messed up. Any help or suggestion on what to do is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing this

```
df = df.T
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = df.iloc[0] # this will set the zeroth index as columns
df = df[1:] # this will remove the zeroth index from the dataframe
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.index.name = None
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252643/discussion-on-answer-by-manoj-biroj-reseting-index-in-dataframe-on-axis-0); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.